# Animation is not working in IE but working in firefox

Tags: jquery, css

Hi i animated the background image. In Firefox it is working fine but on IE it is giving me error that `$(header.css(...) is null or not an object)`. Here is my code

```
var $header = $(".overlayBox");
$header.css("backgroundPosition", "0 0");

var bgScroll = function() {

    **var current = parseInt($header.css("backgroundPosition").split(" ")[1]),   //This is the line that IE is mentioning**      
    newBgPos = "0 " + (current - 1) + "px";
    //Finally we set the new background-position using jQuery's css() method.
    $header.css("backgroundPosition", newBgPos);

} //end of bgScroll()

setInterval(function() { bgScroll() }, 75);
```

Why it is not working in IE ? Also I am using overlay. In Firefox When i click on overlay then overlay disappear. But on IE When i am clicking on overlay, then nothing happening. Here is the code for this

```
// close it when closeLink is clicked
$('a.closeLink').click( doOverlayClose );    

function doOverlayOpen() {

    //set status to open
    isOpen = true;
    showOverlayBox();
    ...
    addEvents();

    // dont follow the link : so return false.
    return false;

} //end of doOverlayOpen()

function doOverlayClose() {

    //set status to closed
    isOpen = false;
    var test = $(".overlayBox");
    $('.overlayBox').css( 'display', 'none' );   

    $('.bgCover').animate({         //This is not working in IE
        opacity:0
    }, null, null, function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });

} //end of doOverlayClose()

function addEvents() {     //Now working in IE

    //Click out event!
    $(".bgCover").click(function(){
        doOverlayClose();
    });

    //Press Escape event!
    $(document).keypress(function(event){

        // IF Esc key press and popup is visible
        if (event.keyCode==27 && isOpen==true) {
            doOverlayClose();
        }
    }) ;

} //end of addEvents()
```

I also added the close link in my div like

```
<div class="bgCover">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="overlayBox" style="background-image: url(../images/header.jpg)" >

    <div class="overlayContent">

        <a href="javascript:void()" class="closeLink">Close</a>
        ....

    </div>

</div>
```

When i click on close link in the IE, then the `$('.overlayBox').css( 'display', 'none' );` line works but bgcover remains there, mean `$('.bgCover').animate({})` line is not working. Why this is not working in IE :(. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: I am using IE 8. I also edit my question to add further problem. Please check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That might be the problem of hide(), could you try using:

```
$('.bgCover').animate({         //This is not working in IE
        opacity:0
    }, null, null, function() {        
          $(this).attr("style", "display: none"); 
    });
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Strange thing... When i debug my code in IE, then while debugging everything works fine but when i run normally, then `($('.bgCover').animate({}))` not works. Any idea? How it can be...?

Answer (score 0):

Fix for backgroung position

```
if ($.browser.msie) {

        current = parseInt($header.css("backgroundPositionY"));

} else {

        current = parseInt($header.css("backgroundPosition").split(" ")[1]);

}
```

Overlay fix

```
showOverlayBox();

if ($.browser.msie) {

    $('.bgCover').css("opacity", 0.5);

} else {

    $('.bgCover').css({

        opacity:0

    }).animate( {

        opacity:0.5,
        backgroundColor:'#000'

    }); //end of animate

}
```

Then code starts to seem work on both browsers. I don't know what effect, animate() in the doOverlayOpen() method was creating on the code, so the events as well as the bgCover was not disappearing. Well this code worked for me at-least.
Thanks